# Is there an elegant way to handle run-time dependent object composition without using dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, composition, dynamic-cast

**Context**

I'm attempting to design a modelling framework that is modular and easy to extend and test. (I'm trying to follow open/closed, dependency injection, and composition over inheritence principles).

I have a hierachy of model objects, which contain methods, some common to all and others specific to certain models. I also have a hierachy of estimation methods which work on various subsets of the models.

Each estimator class requires a model object, which is passed using the constructor.

While constructing the objects at compile is no problem, I'm struggling to come up with a way to do so in run-time without resorting to dynamic_casting of parent model interface in the estimator.
While it works, it's potentially unsafe if an invalid combination of model and estimator are put together. I've also read that dynamic_casting is usually a sign of poor code design.

**Question**

Are there any standard design patterns or techniques to avoid using *dynamic_cast* when object composition details are only known at run-time?

Or does this suggest the object hierachy needs to be completely reworked to avoid this kind of conditional dependency between objects?

**Code Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class i_model {
public:
    virtual double getparameter_a() = 0;
 };

class i_model_A : public i_model {
public:
    virtual double getparameter_b() = 0;
};

class model_A : public i_model_A {
public:
    double getparameter_a() { return 4.0; };
    double getparameter_b() { return 4.0; };
};

class i_model_B : public i_model {
public:
    virtual double getparameter_c() = 0;
};

class model_B : public i_model_B {
public:
    double getparameter_a() { return 5.0; };
    double getparameter_c() { return 2.0; };
};

class i_estimator {
public:
    virtual double getestimate() = 0;
};

class estimator_1 : public i_estimator {
public:
    estimator_1(i_model* in) : model(dynamic_cast<i_model_A*>(in)) {};
    double getestimate() { return model->getparameter_a() + model->getparameter_b(); };
private:
    i_model_A* model;
};

class estimator_2 : public i_estimator {
public:
    estimator_2(i_model* in) : model(dynamic_cast<i_model_B*>(in)) {};
    double getestimate() { return model->getparameter_a() + model->getparameter_c(); };
private:
    i_model_B* model;
};

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    i_model* model = nullptr;
    i_estimator* estimator = nullptr;

    std::cout << "Select model: ";
    std::cin >> a;

    std::cout << "\nSelect estimator: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    
    switch(a) {
    case 1: model = new model_A(); break;
    case 2: model = new model_B(); break;
    }

    switch (b) {
    case 1: estimator = new estimator_1(model); break;
    case 2: estimator = new estimator_2(model); break;
    }
    std::cout << "\nEstimator value = " << estimator->getestimate();
}
```

Comment: `estimator_1(i_model* in) : model(dynamic_cast<i_model_A*>(in))` soooo why take `i_model` if you need `i_model_A` anyway? Aaaand `getparameter_b` and `_c` should just go to `i_model`.

Comment: The model type is only known at run-time;

Comment: The code you posted is going to break if `a` == 1 and `b` == 2, or vice-versa.

Comment: Have a single `i_model` interface having 3 functions. Returns 0 from derived classes when not applicable. Then each estimator call the method it needs.

Comment: @Paul Sanders
Yes, that's one of the reasons I wanted to see if there's a better way to do this. I could put checks on the user inputs to see if combinations are valid (storing valid combinations in a register perhaps), but not sure that is the best approach.

Comment: @Phil1970
In reality the number of models and functions is going to be very large so I don't think it would be feasible. Also, doesn't that break the open/closed principle? The parent interface would need rewriting for every new model.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: if `estimator_1` can only accept an `i_model_A` you're setting yourself up for unforced errors by allowing `i_model`s to be passed in in the first place. Constructors can't benefit from `i_estimator`'s interface, so why  make them all suffer the same parameters? I think you're abstracting in the wrong spot.

Comment: @user4581301
I agree - this is one of the main reasons for the question. I just can't think of way to make this work in run-time without dynamic casting.

Comment: `std::variant` and the visitor pattern?

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a closer look at the visitor pattern. High level, I though it was more for when you have a fixed number of derived classes but want to easily add new methods across them.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand certain estimators only work with certain types of models, but you allow the user to pick whatever estimator and whatever model they want at runtime and then you try to smash them together regardless of whether they fit.

If this is the behavior you want, then no matter what it's possible for the user to select an incompatible model and estimator, so no matter what kind of code you write it's possible to fail at runtime.  Runtime failure is in this case correct behavior, so there's no way to eliminate this possibility using the type system (or any other means).

**EDIT**: The above is slightly incorrect because `dynamic_cast` returns `nullptr` on pointers when the cast fails, and then you get a null pointer dereference which is UB.  It would be correct if you were using references instead of pointers, in which case a failed `dynamic_cast` throws an exception.  Alternatively, if you want to use pointers, do an explicit null check on the result and throw.

Comment: Yeah, the reason I went down this route was it gives a nice seperation between estimation algorithms and model data, making it easy to reuse code or extend both.

Re: run-time failures, I could put restrictions on the user inputs to prevent incompatible combinations (i.e. some sort of structure mapping input combinations to object creation).

I'm just trying to get a sense of whether this approach is going to get me in trouble further down the line. (The consensus seems to be that it's not a great approach, which is good to know). I just need to figure out how to restructure it...

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with it if that's the approach you want.  For instance, if you were writing a compiler, then any text file is accepted as input, and then if you discover that the user has written something like `std::exp("Hello");` you just give a message indicating the user has made a syntax error and exit.  This is not a deficiency on the part of the compiler that it works this way, and there's no design pattern that you could use to write a compiler that can't encounter syntax errors.  The issue is at a different level of abstraction than the code.

Comment: In other words, if this is how the program is supposed to work, there's nothing wrong with writing the code the way you have.

Answer (score 1):

> While it works, it's potentially unsafe if an invalid combination of model and estimator are put together.

The code you have written is very unsafe, it has undefined behaviour if the user picks an invalid combination.

You should ensure there is *some* specified behaviour in that case. E.g.

```
class estimator_1 : public i_estimator {
public:
    estimator_1(i_model_A& in) : model(in) {};
    double getestimate() { return model.getparameter_a() + model.getparameter_b(); };
private:
    i_model_A& model;
};

class estimator_2 : public i_estimator {
public:
    estimator_2(i_model_B& in) : model(in) {};
    double getestimate() { return model.getparameter_a() + model.getparameter_c(); };
private:
    i_model_B& model;
};

i_model* make_model(int choice) {
    switch(choice) {
    case 1: return new model_A();
    case 2: return new model_B();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

i_estimator* make_estimator(int choice, i_model * model) {
    switch (choice) {
    case 1: if (i_model_A* model_a = dynamic_cast<i_model_A*>(model)) return new estimator_1(*model_a); break;
    case 2: if (i_model_B* model_b = dynamic_cast<i_model_B*>(model)) return new estimator_2(*model_b); break;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;

    std::cout << "Select model: ";
    std::cin >> a;

    std::cout << "\nSelect estimator: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    
    auto model = make_model(a);

    if (auto estimator = make_estimator(b, model)) {
        std::cout << "\nEstimator value = " << estimator->getestimate();
    } /* else? */
}
```

N.b. you should also probably use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `*` for owning pointers.

Comment: Thanks. I like the fact this catches the undefined cases automatically.